# Configure subdomain (e.g. intranet.something.rs) in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am running tests with a web-framework that check the routes of a normal webspace and an intranet webspace. The test runner requests the following URLs:

- something.rs
- intranet.something.rs

When running the tests locally I can configure `intranet.something.rs` to point to localhost and the web framework takes care of rerouting the request to the intranet. What settings have to be made in Gitlab CI to make this work?

Ideally a setting in `gitlab-ci.yml` would take care of this, that is transferred to the webserver. The CI system is a self-hosted Linux VM.

Comment: What type of runner are you using? E.g. ssh, docker, shell?

Comment: Oke. Do you use gitlab.com or a selfhosted gitlab? And did you configure the runner?

Comment: I understand but I mean the runner where your jobs are executed. The Gitlab ci multirunner that handles the jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a route to the hosts file of your runner (the Ubuntu VM) in this case.

So add a command before you test:

```
job:
  script:
    - echo "127.0.0.1  intranet.something.rs" >> /etc/hosts
```

This will resolve all requests to `intranet.something.rs` to localhost.

Comment: I think the issue is that when `intranet.something.rs` redirects to `127.0.0.1`, then my web framework is not intelligent enough to load the correct webspace and it is as though I loaded `something.rs` -> `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I guess could seperate my tests into 2 groups and rewrite the host file after the `something.rs` tests are done and before I start the `intranet.something.rs` tests.

Comment: Adding hosts routes do not rewrite, they resolve so your browser or tests will think they are at `intranet.something.rs`.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. It did not work because I has something else configured wrong in the framework. Adding that line was correct and now everything works. Thanks!